# Correcting order of evaluation on JavaScript using multiple .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm suffering to make this code synchronous in JavaScript.

The comments (1,2 and 3) says what happens in order, right now it saves owner before possibly creating a new bar.

I need findOne, possibly saveBar, then saveOwner.

```
function setMyBar(req, res, next) {
  const owner = req.queryOwner;
  Bar.findOne({
    placeId: req.body.placeId
  })
    .then((bar) => {
      if(bar){
        owner.bar = bar; //1
        return owner;
      }else{
        barCtrl.saveBar(req.body.name, req.body.placeId, req.body.longitude, req.body.latitude)
        .then((savedBar) => {
          owner.bar = savedBar; //3
          return owner;
        })
        .catch(e => {return Promise.reject(err) })
      }
    }).then(() => {
      owner.save()
        .then(savedOwner => res.json(savedOwner)) //2
        .catch(e => next(e));
    })
    .catch(e => next(e));
}
```

Comment: Using promises does not make code synchronous. It just helps making asynchronous code sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the promise in the first `then()` in the  `else` condition. Right now nothing is returned so it jumps to the next `then` before `barCtrl.saveBar()` ever resolves

Try

```
 Bar.findOne({
    placeId: req.body.placeId
  })
    .then((bar) => {
      if(bar){
        owner.bar = bar; //1
        return owner;
      }else{
       // return this promise
       return barCtrl.saveBar(req.body.name, req.body.placeId, req.body.longitude, req.body.latitude)
        .then((savedBar) => {
          owner.bar = savedBar; //3
          return owner;
        })
        .catch(e => {return Promise.reject(err) })
      }
    }).then(() => {
      owner.save()
        .then(savedOwner => res.json(savedOwner)) //2
        .catch(e => next(e));
    })
    .catch(e => next(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function setMyBar(req, res, next) {
  const owner = req.queryOwner;
  Bar.findOne({
    placeId: req.body.placeId
  })
    .then((bar) => {
      if(bar){
        owner.bar = bar; //1
        return owner;
      }else{
        // return should do the magic
        return barCtrl.saveBar(req.body.name, req.body.placeId, req.body.longitude, req.body.latitude)
        .then((savedBar) => {
          owner.bar = savedBar; //3
          return owner;
        })
        .catch(e => {return Promise.reject(err) })
      }
    }).then(() => {
      owner.save()
        .then(savedOwner => res.json(savedOwner)) //2
        .catch(e => next(e));
    })
    .catch(e => next(e));
}
```

when you return something within a promise it is returned as a Promise. 
and to chain the promise your current promise must return a promise. which you where not doing

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a lot by using promise chaining:

```
function setMyBar(req, res, next) {
  Bar.findOne({
    placeId: req.body.placeId
  }).then(bar => {
    if (bar) {
      return bar;
    } else {
      return barCtrl.saveBar(req.body.name, req.body.placeId, req.body.longitude, req.body.latitude);
    }
  }).then(savedBar => {
    const owner = req.queryOwner;
    owner.bar = savedBar;
    return owner.save();
  }).then(savedOwner => {
    res.json(savedOwner);
  }, e => {
    next(e);
  });
}
```

The important changes:

- `return` the `saveBar` promise so that it will be awaited and you can use its result in the next (outer) `then` callback
- put the `ownwer.bar` assignment in the next callback, and just `return bar` if the query already found it, to avoid code duplication
- Drop the pointless `.catch(e => {return Promise.reject(err) })`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use the ES7 async functions or async/await syntax, which enables you to write your code A LOT more synchronous with it still being executed asynchronously and in parallel if you wish so. It is supported in all current versions of the major browsers (except IE) and also in Google's V8 engine, which is used by Node.js.

I quickly hacked your code to use async/await syntax, there might be the odd error in there as I just wanted to show you the pros of using async functions. It should look something like this:

```
async function setMyBar(req, res, next) {
    const owner = req.queryOwner;
    try {
        let bar = await Bar.findOne({
            placeId: req.body.placeId
        });

        if (bar) {
            owner.bar = bar;
        } else {
            let savedBar = await barCtrl.saveBar(req.body.name, req.body.placeId, req.body.longitude, req.body.latitude);
            owner.bar = savedBar;
        }

        res.json(await owner.save());
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

Also note that the async keyword in the async function declaration ensures that your function always returns a promise!

Some great links to read up on the functionality, also providing some further background on promises:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions

https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8